# cURL отправка файла через URL

Tags: php, curl

Нужно отправить файл (изображение) на [этот](http://uploads.ru/) сайт.
У них есть [API](http://uploads.ru/apidocs). 
Пробую отправлять с локального сайта (на OpenServer'e), если подставляю адрес картинки в интернете, то все норм, а если указываю таким же образом (полный URL) на своем локальном "сайте", то выдает ошибку 403 (ошибка на ресурс).

```
$img_name_loc = '33.jpg';
```

//  $ch = curl_init('http://uploads.ru/api?upload=http://www.bugaga.ru/uploads/posts/2017-03/1488368729_v-parke-yellouston-11.jpg&thumb_width=800&format=json'); // <- **так работает**

```
$ch = curl_init('http://uploads.ru/api?upload=http://site.loc/uploads/'.$img_name_loc.'&thumb_width=800&format=json');  // <- **так НЕ работает**

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

в идеале было бы, вообще отправлять напрямую из `<input id="uplimg" type="file" accept="image/*">`
Подозреваю, что одна из проблем в том, что это локалка.

Comment: Что то непонятно - два раза "локальный сайт" написан в вопросе.

Comment: что непонятно и где два раза? с локалки пытаюсь отправить на [http://uploads.ru/](http://uploads.ru/) в вопросе указан как "[этот](http://uploads.ru/) сайт"

Comment: 403 curl выдает или API ? И локальный сайт на каком домене развернут?

Comment: API в ответе выдает. Когда изображение из интернета, то нормальный ответ 200 и нужные мне параметры, когда с локалки, то 403 и текст ошибки. Локалка site.loc, в коде строка `$ch = curl_init('http://uploads.ru/api?upload=http://site.loc/uploads/'.$img_name_loc.'&thumb_width=800&format=json');`

Comment: Ваш site.loc виден только вам и только на вашей локальной сети, uploads.ru - это сайт в Интернете, и не знает о нём т.к. доменной имя, опять же, известно только в ВАШЕЙ локальной сети. Используйте POST для передачи изображения (хотя непонятно как именно, и примеров нет), попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433542/curl-php-send-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно проблема в том, что это локалка.

Сайт http://uploads.ru пытается загрузить изображение по переданном Вами адресу условно через `file_get_contents`, и если для вас http://test1.ru/33.jpg открывается, то для uploads.ru это будет совершенно другой ресурс, который и отдает ему 403.

В API написано, что

- Загрузка файлов с компьютера или интернета
- Работает с POST и GET

Но, примеров локальной загрузки нету, ВОЗМОЖНО стоит передать просто локальный путь, например как у Вас начале написано - '33.jpg', API определит что нету указания протокола и это локальный путь.

Comment: Решил все же проверить свое подозрение и Ваше утверждение насчет локалки. Действительно, проблема в этом. Просто передать локальный путь - не прокатит, но попробую поиграться с `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];`, может получится все же с `input'a` напрямую кидать, миную свой сервак